How can I change the position of popup using the MAUI toolkit?
I am wondering how do I change position of popup from toolkit. I expect something like this:

I am trying something like this:
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
               xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
               xmlns:popups="clr-namespace:xxx"
               x:Class="xxx.SelectPopup"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Start"
               >
    
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="This is a very important message!" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>

</toolkit:Popup>

But I've noticed I can change only HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions, but I can't change AbsoluteLayout or Anchor (more custom way). How can I achive something like from screen?
Also I am trying with AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="100, 200, 20, 20" in <toolkit:Popup but nothing happened.
I use .NET 8.0, MAUI 8.0.40

There's no API to set the absolute position of the Popup. You may raise a feature request on GitHub for that.
According to your scenario, you may try using Anchor property of Popup, e.g. when click the Button,
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var popup = new MyPopup();

        //set the Anchor to the Button,

        popup.Anchor = sender as Button;
        this.ShowPopup(popup);
    }

this will set the Popup close to the Button control.
Or  you may trying creating your own custom control instead of Popup view. Then you could set the custom control using the absolute position.

Thanks for reply. This solution works for me but popup appears in the middle of button. Do you know how can I add some margin?

I will wrap the layout with a Border. Set the BackgroundColor of Border to transparent and set the margin for the layout in the Border.

Thanks to Liqun Shen-MSFT I've achieved that with this:
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
               xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
               xmlns:popups="clr-namespace:xxx"
               x:Class="xxx"
               Color="Transparent"
               >
    <Border BackgroundColor="Transparent" Stroke="Transparent" >
        <Label Margin="0, 90, 0, 0" BackgroundColor="Green" Text="Test Text" />
    </Border>
</toolkit:Popup>

For my case it was crucial to add Color="Transparent" for popup.

"I've achieved that" what is "that" referring to? Adding margin or what you asked for in the question above?
